Why is list property not iterated properly?
When providing a list of strings as a parameter property, and coalescing with another list of strings, Azure devops fails to interpret the string list properly.
Works
Coalescing one string list parameter with another string list parameter.
parameters:
- name: group
  type: object
  default:
  - 'myGroup'
- name: resourceNames
  type: object
  default:
  - 'name1'
  - 'name2'

jobs:
- job: TestJob

  steps:  
  - ${{ each n in coalesce(parameters.resourceNames, parameters.group) }}:
    - script: echo ${{ n }}

This results in 2 cmdLine tasks, outputting name1 and name2
Works
Iterating over a list property of a parameter that is a list of objects.
parameters:
- name: resources
  type: object
  default:
  - resourceNames:
    - 'name1'
    - 'name2'

jobs:
- job: TestJob

  steps:  
  - ${{ each r in parameters.resources }}:
    - ${{ each n in r.resourceNames}}:
      - script: echo ${{ n }}

This also results in 2 cmdLine tasks, outputting name1 and name2
Doesn't work
Iterating over a list property of a parameter that is a list of objects, coalesced with a string list parameter.
parameters:
- name: group
  type: object
  default:
  - 'myGroup'
- name: resources
  type: object
  default:
  - resourceNames:
    - 'name1'
    - 'name2'

jobs:
- job: TestJob

  steps:  
  - ${{ each r in parameters.resources }}:
    - ${{ each n in coalesce(r.resourceNames, parameters.group) }}:
      - script: echo ${{ n }}

This results in validation error: /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 19, Col: 17): Unable to convert from Object to String. Value: Object
The problematic bit is the script, echo ${{ n }}. For some reason Devops thinks n is an object, when it should in fact be a string. See answer below, where n is converted to json and looks like {"lit":"name1"...} Is this a bug, or does anyone know if I can get the coalesce working with a list property of a list param?

You can check the value of n with convertToJson expression, it's actually an object.
- job: TestJob
  steps:  
  - ${{ each r in parameters.resources }}:    
    - ${{ each n in coalesce(r.resourceNames, parameters.group) }}:
      - script: echo ${MY_JSON3}
        env:
          MY_JSON3: ${{ convertToJson(n) }}   # check the n value.


To iterate through the list, you should fix the list format in parameter and use correct each string.
You can refer to the parameter sample below, need to remove dash - before resourceNames in your parameter definition.

And use below expression, go to resourceNames level to  literate through the list:
  - ${{ each n in coalesce(parameters.resources.resourceNames, parameters.group) }}:
      - script: echo ${{ n }}

The completed fixed yaml:
parameters:
- name: group
  type: object
  default:
  - 'myGroup'
- name: resources
  type: object
  default:
   resourceNames:               # remove dash - before resourceNames
    - 'name1'
    - 'name2'


jobs:
- job: TestJob
  steps:  
  - ${{ each n in coalesce(parameters.resources.resourceNames, parameters.group) }}:     # go to resourceNames level to literate through the list.
      - script: echo ${{ n }}


Edit:
As per your comment, it appears you have below parameters:
parameters:
- name: group
  type: object
  default:
  - 'myGroup'
- name: resources
  type: object
  default:
  - resourceType: app
    resourceNames: 
    - 'name1' 
    - 'name2'
  - resourceType: storageAccount
    resourceNames: 
    - 'name1' 
    - 'name3'

You can get the coalesce working with below yaml:
jobs:
- job: TestJob
  steps:  
  - ${{ each r in parameters.resources }} : # Iterate over each r in the 'resources'
    - ${{ each n in r.resourceNames}} : # Iterate over each n in the current resource names.
      - script: echo ${{ coalesce(n, parameters.group) }}    # coalescing with another list of string and output.

Edit2:
If resourceNames is optional, sample parameter as below:
parameters:
- name: group
  type: object
  default:
  - 'myGroup'
- name: resources
  type: object
  default:
  - resourceType: app
    resourceNames: 
    - 'name1' 
    - 'name2'
  - resourceType: newapp
  - resourceType: storageAccount
    resourceNames: 
    - 'name1' 
    - 'name3'
  - resourceType: testapp

You can use if expression between each loop to evaluate, and output conditionally， yaml below:
  - ${{ each r in parameters.resources }} : # Iterate over each r in the 'resources'
    - ${{ if r.resourceNames}}:
      - ${{ each n in r.resourceNames}} : # Iterate over each n in the current resource names.
        - script: echo ${{ n }}    
    - ${{ else }}:
      - script: echo ${{ parameters.group[0] }}



resources is a list, and resourceNames is a list property on each resource. In my actual pipeline, I have several resources listed and each has several properties. So your suggestion will not work for my use case.

Here's a sample default value for resources that will give you a better idea of what I am trying to accomplish
  default:
  - resourceType: app
    resourceNames:
    - 'name1'
    - 'name2'
  - resourceType: storageAccount
    resourceNames:
    - 'name1'
    - 'name3'


See updated question above

@Rachel, i tried to follow your parameter and add edit in my answer, please have a check. If it's not your parameter, please edit the ticket and update the sample parameter. thanks.

Thank you! The problem is that resourceNames is optional, and when not supplied I'd like to use group, so I need to coalesce n.resourceNames and group. For example add to the parameter default - resourceType: groupResource, this should output myGroup

@Rachel, thanks for the update. If resourceNames is optional, you can use if expression in each to evaluate and then output. Please check my Edit2 for the sample.

It's a complex task, not simply the echo which I provided as an example, so I don't want to repeat it as an if. I'd like to coalesce the two lists, the way it works when coalescing one string list parameter with another string list parameter in my first example in the original question.

@Rachel, since the resourceNames is optional, due to your parameter hierarchy, i'm afraid you cannot simply coalesce {last level element} with group Resource as expected.  You could have to use if expression so similar way then you can iterate the properly. Thanks.

zhou can you explain why I can't coalesce an optional field? Isn't the entire use case for coalesce when you have a nullable value? Also, the yaml is valid when resourceNames isn't provided at all e.g. change the default value to just - resourceType: groupResource and it will output myGroup

@Rachel, the resourceNames is under resourceType, and it's optional, which means it could no exist,  if you simply coalesce, either loose case when resourceNames doesn't exit, or output is object as before. Using if expression can resolve both cases and get expected output.
